# Modeling an action and reaction flow in Prolog

Tags: prolog, logic, logic-programming

I want to model an action and reaction flow in Prolog. For example in a two player game with dice there are two elements of luck and play. When dice rolls a low value it is bad luck and when player makes a good move it is good play. So we can have these sample queries:

```
reaction(good, luck, player).
reaction(bad, play, opponent).
```

There is a list of reactions like emojis which express the player feeling on the given action. And for every feeling like happiness or anger there are more than one emoji but only one should be chosen preferably random or with weighted random.

I am new to Prolog and I am having trouble in modeling this in it. I would like explanations to achieving answer instead of pure code to grow my logic mindset.

Thanks in advance.

I also have read [this tutorial](http://www.doc.gold.ac.uk/~mas02gw/prolog_tutorial/prologpages/index.html) and tried [this guide](http://www.amzi.com/manuals/samples/prolog/chat_ontology/doc.html) on ontology with chatbots.

---

**More detailed examples**

There are four actions in the game: bad luck, good luck, bad play, good play.
All actions could happen to either of two players.
For example opponent rolls a dice with low number triggers action 'bad luck opponent' or player make a successful move triggers action 'good play player'.
The reaction predicate should return player emoji reaction to these in game actions.

```
?- reaction(bad, luck, opponent).
the_face_with_tears_of_joy_emoji;

?- reaction(good, play, player).
arm_flexing_emoji;

?- reaction(good, play, opponent).
angry_face_emoji;
```

Comment: Could you define in more details the meaning of the `reaction` predicate?

Comment: @RobertBaron I have added more detaied examples.

Comment: Prolog is quite different from other programming language. You have to start thinking in terms of the conditions that make a predicate true, rather than a predicate returning something as you say in your last sentence "The reaction predicate should return player emoji reaction to these in game actions."

Comment: The first thing to define is what is the main goal predicate. You mentioned that `reaction(good, luck, player).` is a sample input. How is this input given to your main goal predicate?

Comment: @RobertBaron sorry I meant query not input, I've edited it.

Comment: I still do not understand what your main goal is. How are you going to use Prolog to solve your problem? You have to be able to state something like, "main_goal(-X1,-X2,+X3,...) is true when such and such conditions are true of X1, X2, X3, ...". I am trying to guide you in understanding and explaining your problem. You have to understand that if you cannot clearly explain what your problem is, it is unlikely that anyone will be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to approach this would be to just make a table of the reactions:

```
reaction(bad, luck, opponent, the_face_with_tears_of_joy_emoji).
reaction(good, play, player, arm_flexing_emoji).
reaction(good, play, opponent, angry_face_emoji).
```

When you issue your query, the result is the final parameter:

```
?- reaction(good, play, player, Reaction).
Reaction = arm_flexing_emoji.
```

Probably you'll have some other tables to tell you other facts about your situation:

```
roll_quality(1, bad).
roll_quality(2, bad).
roll_quality(3, bad).
roll_quality(4, good).
roll_quality(5, good).
roll_quality(6, good).
```

Then your query will get a little more interesting:

```
?- roll_quality(Roll, RollQuality), reaction(RollQuality, luck, player, Reaction).
```

For instance.